# Given a reference to function, produce it's source code without annotations in the signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

Default values should remain.

Decorators should also be removed, but it's less of a concern.

Original source:

```py
# Comments
@decorator1
@decorator2(
    a=1,
    b=1,
)
def my_func(
    a: typing.List = 14,
    b: 'CustomType' = None,
    c: Whatever('foo') = 42,
    d: Whatever('foo') = some_function,
) -> typing.NamedTuple(
    'Dummy',
    [
      ('r1': 'CustomType'),
      ('21': 'CustomType2'),
    ]
):
    ...
```

Desired source:

```py
def my_func(
    a = 14,
    b = None,
    c = 42,
    d = some_function,
):
    ...
```

I can get the source using `inspect.getsource(my_func)`, but I need to strip the annotations.
How can I do this? Preferably using the standard modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `lib2to3.refactor.RefactoringTool` to refactor the code using a fixer that is a subclass of `lib2to3.fixer_base.BaseFix` with a pattern that looks for either a typed argument, a function declaration with an annotated returning value, or a decorated definition, and a `transform` method that removes the indices of the annotations and decorators from the child nodes:

```
from lib2to3 import fixer_base, refactor

class FixParameterAnnotations(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    PATTERN = "name=tname | func=funcdef< any+ '->' any+ > | decorated"

    def transform(self, node, results):
        if 'name' in results:
            del node.children[1:] # delete annotation to typed argument
        elif 'func' in results:
            del node.children[-4:-2] # delete annotation to function declaration
        else:
            del node.children[0] # delete decorators
        return node

class Refactor(refactor.RefactoringTool):
    def __init__(self, fixers):
        self._fixers= [cls(None, None) for cls in fixers]
        super().__init__(None)

    def get_fixers(self):
        return self._fixers, []
```

so that:

```
import inspect
import typing
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('builtins.print')
def my_func(
        a: int = 1, # some comment
        b: typing.List = []     # more comment
) -> bool:
    ''' some docstring'''
    pass

print(Refactor([FixParameterAnnotations]).refactor_string(inspect.getsource(my_func), ''))
```

outputs:

```
def my_func(
        a = 1, # some comment
        b = []     # more comment
):
    ''' some docstring'''
    pass
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/BrightWhirlwindBoolean

`lib2to3` is round-trip stable so all comments and white spaces are preserved after the transformation. You can find the definition of the Python grammar in [`Grammar.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/Grammar.txt) of the `lib2to3` module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.parse` to parse the source into an AST, and use `ast.walk` to traverse the tree to nullify `annotation` if it's an `arg` node and nullify `returns` and `decorator_list` if it's a `FunctionDef` node. Use [`astunparse`](https://pypi.org/project/astunparse/) to unparse the tree back to source code:

```
import inspect
import ast
import typing
import astunparse
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('builtins.print')
def my_func(
        a: int = 1,
        b: typing.List = []
) -> bool:
    pass

tree = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(my_func), '', 'exec')
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.arg):
        node.annotation = None
    elif isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
        node.returns = None
        node.decorator_list = []
print(astunparse.unparse(tree))
```

This outputs:

```
def my_func(a=1, b=[]):
    pass
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/WaterloggedFunnyQuotient

Comment: Is the `unparse(ast.parse(...))` roundtrip stable? Have you seen any cases where it changes something about the code? Does it try to preserve the code syntax?

Comment: Do you think it would be easy to make it stop parsing after the function signature and just copy the remaining source intact?

Comment: `ast.parse` doesn't preserve comments or line numbers since they are not part of an Abstract Syntax Tree. To do that you need a parser that parses code into a Full Syntax Tree. See the other answer of mine using `lib2to3` for such a solution.